# SQL query using case and Group by aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following situation:

1 Table for a Warehouse where I have: the ProductID, the qty and the address
1 Table for the Stores Where I have: The ProductID and qty
1 table for the Stores Storage addresses

What I need to know is if a product is "in Stock" or "out of Stock" using the criteria that for a product to be considered "out of stock" it has to have qty >=0  or >20k in both tables (stores and warehouse)

What I have tried is the following:

```
SELECT Product_Cod, qty_wh, QtyStore,
    CASE
        WHEN sum(QtyStore) BETWEEN 1 AND 20000 THEN 
                                CASE
                                        WHEN qty_wh > 0 THEN 'In Stock'
                                        WHEN qty_wh = 0 THEN 'In Stock'
                                END
        WHEN sum(QtyStore) = 0 OR sum(QtyStore) > 20000 THEN
                                CASE
                                        WHEN qty_wh <= 0 THEN 'Out of Stock'
                                        WHEN qty_wh > 0 THEN 'in Stock'
                                END
    END AS [Result]
FROM tb_Products, tb_qtyStock, tb_StoreProdAddress
WHERE Product_Cod = wh_CodProduct
AND Product_Cod = Store_CodProduct
GROUP BY Product_Cod, qty_wh, QtyStore 
ORDER BY Product_Cod
```

Which outputs:

```
   ProdCod qty_wh QtyStore   Result
    10026   26      0       In Stock
    10026   26      1       In Stock
    10026   26      2       In Stock
    10070   25      0       In Stock
    10070   25      2       In Stock
    10070   25      3       In Stock
    10071   20      0       In Stock
    10071   20      1       In Stock
    10071   20      29991   In Stock
    10072   32      0       In Stock
    10072   32      1       In Stock
    10072   32      29978   In Stock
    10204   0       0       Out of Stock
    10204   0       1       In Stock
    10204   0       4       In Stock
    10204   0       29996   Out of Stock
```

But I can't make it work like I want because the QtyStore column doesn't SUM()
it repeats because the tb_StoreProdAddress is used for several stores so Multiple stores can have the same product but each store may have a different address for that product, but the address for given product in the warehouse is the same.

There is a way to SUM() the QtyStore column and just Group the qty_wh ???

Comment: Yhe reason you can't use sum on it is because it's in the group by clause.
Have you tried taking the `QtyStore` column out of the group by clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the QtyStore column from your `GROUP BY` clause, and put `SUM(QtyStore)` in the `SELECT`-part of your query.

```
SELECT Product_Cod, qty_wh, SUM(QtyStore) AS TotalQtyStore,
    CASE
        WHEN sum(QtyStore) BETWEEN 1 AND 20000 THEN 
                                CASE
                                        WHEN qty_wh > 0 THEN 'In Stock'
                                        WHEN qty_wh = 0 THEN 'In Stock'
                                END
        WHEN sum(QtyStore) = 0 OR sum(QtyStore) > 20000 THEN
                                CASE
                                        WHEN qty_wh <= 0 THEN 'Out of Stock'
                                        WHEN qty_wh > 0 THEN 'in Stock'
                                END
    END AS [Result]
FROM tb_Products, tb_qtyStock, tb_StoreProdAddress
WHERE Product_Cod = wh_CodProduct
AND Product_Cod = Store_CodProduct
GROUP BY Product_Cod, qty_wh
ORDER BY Product_Cod
```

Comment: Thank you Dan! I'm pretty sure I tried that yesterday, but screwed it up somewhere because the actual query has way more to it, this is the short version of it, but now it is working like a charm! Blind spot, guess just needed another set of eyes to see my mistake XD

Answer (score 1):

You could try maxing qty_wth then summing QtyStore like so:

```
SELECT Product_Cod, max(qty_wh) as qty_wh, sum(QtyStore) as QtyStore,
    CASE
        WHEN sum(QtyStore) BETWEEN 1 AND 20000 THEN 
                            CASE
                                    WHEN qty_wh > 0 THEN 'In Stock'
                                    WHEN qty_wh = 0 THEN 'In Stock'
                            END
        WHEN sum(QtyStore) = 0 OR sum(QtyStore) > 20000 THEN
                            CASE
                                    WHEN qty_wh <= 0 THEN 'Out of Stock'
                                    WHEN qty_wh > 0 THEN 'in Stock'
                            END
END AS [Result]
FROM tb_Products, tb_qtyStock, tb_StoreProdAddress
WHERE Product_Cod = wh_CodProduct
AND Product_Cod = Store_CodProduct
GROUP BY Product_Cod
ORDER BY Product_Cod
```

Answer (score 1):

to avoid to make the same operation multiple times,  you can do your calcul in subquery :

```
SELECT Product_Cod,
       qty_wh,
       QtyStore,
       CASE
          WHEN QtyStore BETWEEN 1 AND 20000
          THEN
             CASE
                WHEN qty_wh > 0 THEN 'In Stock'
                WHEN qty_wh = 0 THEN 'In Stock'
             END
          WHEN QtyStore = 0 OR QtyStore > 20000
          THEN
             CASE
                WHEN qty_wh <= 0 THEN 'Out of Stock'
                WHEN qty_wh > 0 THEN 'in Stock'
             END
       END AS [Result]
    FROM (SELECT Product_Cod,
               MAX (qty_wh) AS qty_wh,
               SUM (QtyStore) AS QtyStore,
               FROM tb_Products,
               tb_qtyStock,
               tb_StoreProdAddress 
             WHERE Product_Cod = wh_CodProduct
             AND Product_Cod = Store_CodProduct
             GROUP BY Product_Cod)
    ORDER BY Product_Cod
```

I hope it helps.